# How to add text for fadein/fadeout count number jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is my index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //####### on page load, retrive votes for each content
    $.each( $('.voting_wrapper'), function(){

        //retrive unique id from this voting_wrapper element
        var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");

        //prepare post content
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};

        //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
        $.post('vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {

                //retrive votes from server, replace each vote count text
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up); 
            },'json');
    });



    //####### on button click, get user vote and send it to vote_process.php using jQuery $.post().
    $(".voting_wrapper .voting_btn").click(function (e) {

        //get class name (down_button / up_button) of clicked element
        var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');

        //get unique ID from voted parent element
        var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 


        if(clicked_button==='up_button') //user liked the content
        {
            //prepare post content
            post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};

            //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //replace vote up count text with new values
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);

                //thank user for liking the content
            $('#message-status').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert user about the HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }

    });
    //end 

});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.content_wrapper{width:500px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}
h3{color: #979797;border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;font-family: "Trebuchet MS";}

/*voting style */
.voting_wrapper {display:inline-block;margin-left: 20px;}
.voting_wrapper .up_button {background: url(images/index.png) no-repeat;float: left;width: 50px;cursor:pointer;}
.voting_wrapper .up_button:hover{background: url(images/index.png) no-repeat;}
.voting_btn{float:left;margin-right:5px;}
.voting_btn span{font-size: 11px;float: left;margin-left: 3px;}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <h3><img src="9780143332497.jpg" alt=""><br />

        <!-- voting markup -->
        <div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- voting markup end -->
    </h3>
<span id="message-status"></span>
</div>
</body>
```

vote_process.php:

```
<?php
    ####### db config ##########
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = 'voter';
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    ####### db config end ##########

if($_POST)
{

    ### connect to mySql
    $sql_con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');

    //get type of vote from client
    $user_vote_type = trim($_POST["vote"]);

    //get unique content ID and sanitize it (cos we never know).
    $unique_content_id = filter_var(trim($_POST["unique_id"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //Convert content ID to MD5 hash (optional)
    $unique_content_id = hash('md5', $unique_content_id);

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    } 


    switch ($user_vote_type)
    {           

        ##### User liked the content #########
        case 'up': 

            //check if user has already voted, determined by unique content cookie
            if (isset($_COOKIE["voted_".$unique_content_id]))
            {
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 User Already Voted'); //cookie found, user has already voted
                exit(); //exit script
            }

            //get vote_up value from db using unique_content_id
            $result = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT vote_up FROM voting_count WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id' LIMIT 1");
            $get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if($get_total_rows)
            {
                //found record, update vote_up the value
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"UPDATE voting_count SET vote_up=vote_up+1 WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id'");
            }else{
                //no record found, insert new record in db
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"INSERT INTO voting_count (unique_content_id, vote_up) value('$unique_content_id',1)");
            }

            setcookie("voted_".$unique_content_id, 1, time()+7200); // set cookie that expires in 2 hour "time()+7200".
            echo ($get_total_rows["vote_up"]+1); //display total liked votes
            break;  

        ##### respond votes for each content #########      
        case 'fetch':
            //get vote_up and vote_down value from db using unique_content_id
            $result = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT vote_up,vote_down FROM voting_count WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id' LIMIT 1");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            //making sure value is not empty.
            $vote_up    = ($row["vote_up"])?$row["vote_up"]:0; 

            //build array for php json
            $send_response = array('vote_up'=>$vote_up, 'vote_down'=>$vote_down);
            echo json_encode($send_response); //display json encoded values
            break;

    }

}
?>
```

When i run above code, it shows counting number. I had set to showing counting number near by button and also set that counting number as fadein/fadeout.

Now , what i need is, when i click the button, have to add text like users has voted, I mean "10 users has voted"[say for example] and also fadein/fadeout countanumber like this "10 users has voting including you".

So i don't know, where i can add this text with existing count number.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include jsFiddle

Comment: these are my full source code, and may i know, how to create jsfiddle for php, is it possible?

Comment: hi @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com .... are you there?

Comment: yes please wait for an hour only , I have holiday and will be back at 2 PM sure ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this , I hope everything is working well except you want to show some message after voting ALONG with Upvote count.

Modify your index.php at the end:

```
dataModified = data+' users has voting including you';
$('#message-status').hide().html(dataModified).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).hide(1);
```

Comment: See your code , find comment `thank user for liking the content` and add below it.

Comment: thanks @jquery: but i need, when i click the button, have to add text like users has voted, I mean "10 users has voted"[say for example] and also fadein/fadeout countanumber like this "10 users has voting including you", right?. so i need, thats the comment "users has voting including you" to place near by the button also.

Comment: can you please see this link, and is possible to solve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670974/how-to-add-joint-line-for-image-and-description-in-html-and-css3